# What is the problem with typescript switch Case on number in this code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the problem with this code? My switch case does not work correctly.

```
 setSymbol(currentUserCategory: string, filterIndex: number) {
    if (currentUserCategory === Settings.userCategory.seller) {
      console.log('On switch2', filterIndex);
      switch (filterIndex) {
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
          console.log('new symbol');
          this.triSymbol = 'pourcentage';
          break;
        default:
          console.log('On default', filterIndex);
          this.triSymbol = 'money';
          break;
      }
// Other code
}

setSymbol ('seller', 3) // 'On default 3'
```

I use typescript in angular, do i need to parse number with `Number(filterIndex)`?

When i use `Number(filterIndex)` => I get in log '**new symbol**'. I need to parse number to number.

Comment: That means that your number is actually a string.

Comment: A switch statement uses strict type checking like a triple equal `===`, so use `switch (parseInt(filterIndex)) { ... }`

Comment: The code here does not constitute a [mcve], as calling `setSymbol('seller', 3)` [behaves as you intend](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKZQMoE8C2AjOAGwAoIQAnc1MKAVTXIGEBDKVAcznKwC4UpyMMOwA0iYDEJtyASTAATVAA8+YEPlTkAlIgDeAKACQEBMiKoAdITjtiAcgDySZAHcYUCAAsATHbESpTTlFJS0AbiNXdy9EYgDpYOUdA0NjZjREAGYeIzSMgBYc1Ih01EQAViK8soA2KuNTcysbezBUFxRcAkI7cNzDAHoBqE8YZAsBGGx8IkQAXkQ7AAc4CghqKGZ2VDsI1MM8KmYAaz3DRWBmECl6kzAzQktrW0ckC6upP3FJBIUks8Gw1G40m02680WOAQqCwu36h1QJz2AF99Kj9GhMF0iPY0IRHuQvpkdENEAAiNodZDYwhkoA).  If there is a problem, it's not in the code you posted.

Comment: Either use `parseInt(filterIndex)`, `(+filterIndex)` or `Number(filterIndex)` or `parseFloat(filterIndex)` if a float is needed. The argument type definition (`filterIndex: number`) does **not** guarantee that, at runtime, filterIndex will effectively be a number. Regardless typescript has types, you should still take care of type casting. Alternatively, you can think about using **User-Defined Type Guards** to ensure the argument type is as expected. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html

Comment: I check the type and it is  a number, normaly the parameter is of type number , it cast to number type